# Proguard for Android Jetpack compose UI

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, proguard, jetpack

My app will crash in release mode, it works find in debug mode. I suspect something should be kept in Proguard, but can't figure out what's wrong.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
> androidx.compose.ui.text.platform.AndroidParagraphHelper_androidKt.createCharSequence
> (AndroidParagraphHelper_android.kt:48)
> androidx.compose.ui.text.platform.AndroidParagraphIntrinsics.
> (AndroidParagraphIntrinsics.android.kt:48)
> androidx.compose.ui.text.platform.AndroidParagraphIntrinsics_androidKt.ActualParagraphIntrinsics
> (AndroidParagraphIntrinsics_android.kt:38)
> androidx.compose.ui.text.ParagraphIntrinsicsKt.ParagraphIntrinsics
> (ParagraphIntrinsics.kt:38)
> androidx.compose.ui.text.ParagraphIntrinsicsKt.ParagraphIntrinsics$default
> (ParagraphIntrinsics.kt:38)
> androidx.compose.foundation.text.modifiers.ParagraphLayoutCache.setLayoutDirection
> (ParagraphLayoutCache.kt:38)
> androidx.compose.foundation.text.modifiers.ParagraphLayoutCache.b
> (ParagraphLayoutCache.kt:1)
> androidx.compose.foundation.text.modifiers.ParagraphLayoutCache.layoutWithConstraints-K40F9xA
> (ParagraphLayoutCache.kt:215)
> androidx.compose.foundation.text.modifiers.TextStringSimpleNode.measure-3p2s80s
> (TextStringSimpleNode.kt:215)
> androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0
> (LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:11)
> androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.g
> (GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:1)
> androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0
> (LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:11)

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs += [
                    '-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn'
            ]
        }
    }
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs += [
                    '-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I have already add below to Proguard-rules.pro file.

```
# We supply these as stubs and are able to link to them at runtime
# because they are hidden public classes in Android. We don't want
# R8 to complain about them not being there during optimization.
-dontwarn android.view.RenderNode
-dontwarn android.view.DisplayListCanvas
 
-keepclassmembers class androidx.compose.ui.platform.ViewLayerContainer {
    protected void dispatchGetDisplayList(); }

-keepclassmembers class androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView {
    android.view.View findViewByAccessibilityIdTraversal(int); }

# Users can create Modifier.Node instances that implement multiple Modifier.Node interfaces,
# so we cannot tell whether two modifier.node instances are of the same type without using
# reflection to determine the class type. See b/265188224 for more context.
-keep,allowshrinking class * extends androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifierNodeElement


# Keep generic signature of Call, Response (R8 full mode strips signatures from non-kept items).
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking interface retrofit2.Call
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.Response
 
# With R8 full mode generic signatures are stripped for classes that are not
# kept. Suspend functions are wrapped in continuations where the type argument
# is used.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: If you are using ```Data``` class then you need to add ```-keep``` rules for those class and it will save you from crash

Comment: @ChiragThummar This is correct answer!